# .htaccess - How to set expires to date in past?

Tags: .htaccess, yslow, pagespeed

I noticed that Google sets the expiration of its HTML to a date in the past:

```
Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00
```

How do I configure .htaccess to do this? I use `ExpiresByType` to set the expiration of my other resources, but they are all future times (e.g. `access plus 10 years`). Any suggestions on how to set it for the past? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the expiration of the HTML to the past, I'm assuming you're trying to prevent your HTML from being cached. Unfortunately, you cannot use the Expires directive as it only works for future dates. You can use header commands though to control how your HTML files are cached.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

The `mod_headers` module will need to be installed in Apache to use this method.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, if you're using PHP, you can set these headers using PHP's `header` function.

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: thaat is exactly what I am trying to do. What if my HTML files are being serve from PHP? Do I try to FilesMatch "\.php$" instead? And what if the URL has query strings? That $ sign will cause a non-match. Suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you can target PHP files by changing `<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">`. However, you could use the `header` function of PHP as well. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I'm trying for a purely .htaccess solution. What about the issue of query strings? The regex in FilesMatch won't match for, say, `www.domain.com/index.html?q=hello`, right? How do I handle query strings? Removing the $ sign seems dangerous as the query string could potentially have, say, `.php` in it.

Comment: how reliable do you think it would be to use `ExpiresByType text/html "now"`? Would that be enough to tell browsers not to cache the HTML?